# Using Environment Variables when sending mail - CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm configuring CakePHP email and am having trouble using environment variables.  I can get the email function to work when using the standard format (as provided by the CakePHP "Cookbook"), but I would prefer to use environment variables for the username and password fields for security purposes.

This works:

```
public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

This, however, does not:

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => getenv('USERNAME'),
    'password' => getenv('PASSWORD'),
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

The variables are set up correctly, as I'm able to print them to the screen using "echo".  I've also tried this, to no avail:

```
$env_username = getenv('USERNAME');
$env_password = getenv('PASSWORD');
class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => $env_username,
        'password' => $env_password,
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class members can only be initialized with constant values that can be evaluated at compile time (booleans, numbers, strings, etc).

**http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php**

As mentioned the documentation you can define dynamic configuration data in the class constructor:

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration**

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => null,
        'password' => null,
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->gmail['username'] = getenv('USERNAME');
        $this->gmail['password'] = getenv('PASSWORD');
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense - this is what I was missing.  This works perfectly - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your variable in config\core e.g.

```
Configure::write('MyEmailConfig1', array(
       username => 'SetYourUsername',
       password => 'SetYourPassword'
));
```

then you can read it from your config\email. some thing like this...

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => Configure::read('MyEmailConfig1.username'),
    'password' => Configure::read('MyEmailConfig1.password'),
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```